# TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error: TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function, this happens when using CRACO with the latest versions of ts-loader and loader-utils

Answer (score 1):

I share the solution, basically it is that ts-loader does not support webpack 4, it is the one that comes with the react-scripts, this generates the problem, you must downgrade from ts-loader to version 8, something like this: "ts- loader ":" ^8"

I leave you the source: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/595